Error al subir archivo a SharePoint Online usando Office365-REST-Python-Client: 'Cannot get binary security token'
Estoy intentando subir un archivo a una biblioteca de documentos en SharePoint Online utilizando la librería Office365-REST-Python-Client en Python, con el fin de generar un proceso mas robusto para crear backups aprovechando el espacio que tenemos en la organicacion por tener licencias de office 365. Sin embargo, cuando intento autenticarme usando mis credenciales de Office 365, recibo el siguiente error:
Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/onedrive.py", line 21, in <module>
    ctx.execute_query()
  File "/home/user/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_runtime_context.py", line 173, in execute_query
    self.pending_request().execute_query(qry)
  File "/home/user/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_request.py", line 37, in execute_query
    response = self.execute_request_direct(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/user/myenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_request.py", line 46, in execute_request_direct
    self.beforeExecute.notify(request “
  ...
ValueError: Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf


Este es el código que estoy utilizando:
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import os

# Configura tus credenciales y la URL de SharePoint
site_url = 'https://sitio.sharepoint.com/sites/sitio'
username = 'user@domain.com'
password = 'password'
file_path = 'file.json'
destination_folder_url = '/sites/sitio/Documentos/Folder'

# Autenticación y conexión
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(site_url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
    
    # Lee el archivo
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_content:
        # Subir archivo
        target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(destination_folder_url)
        target_file = target_folder.upload_file(os.path.basename(file_path), file_content)
        ctx.execute_query()

    print(f"Archivo {os.path.basename(file_path)} subido correctamente a {destination_folder_url}.")
else:
    print("Error de autenticación")



Contexto Adicional:
Estoy usando una cuenta de Office 365 que tiene acceso a SharePoint Online.
Mi organización no utiliza Azure AD Premium, por lo que no puedo registrar aplicaciones en Azure AD.
Estoy buscando una solución que me permita autenticarme y subir archivos a SharePoint Online usando únicamente las credenciales de Office 365.
¿Por qué estoy recibiendo este error al intentar autenticarme con SharePoint Online? ¿Es posible que este error esté relacionado con la configuración de mi cuenta o con la forma en que la autenticación está configurada en mi organización?

Eso pasa porque la autenticación con credenciales de usuario y contraseña directa en SharePoint Online (bajo Office 365) ya no es compatible.
Debes usar autenticación basada en OAuth con Azure AD o autenticación de aplicaciones modernas (MSAL).
